# Save and Load Custom Tensorflow Model (Autoregressive seq2seq multivariate time series GRU/RNN)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement an autoregressive seq-2-seq RNN to predict time series data, [as shown in this TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#advanced_autoregressive_model). The model consists of a custom model class, inheriting from `tf.keras.Model`, of which the code can be found below.  I have used this model for time series prediction with as input data a (15, 108) dataset (dimensions: (sequence length, input units)) and as output data a (10, 108) dataset.

Although training was succesful, **I have not succeeded to successfully save and reload the model to evaluate previously trained models on a test set.** I have tried looking for solutions on the internet, but none of them seem to work so far. Possibly this is due to since it is a custom model trained using eager execution, as multiple threads could not resolve saving the model in these conditions.

Could anybody give me tips on how to resolve this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Thusfar, I have loaded the model using `tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath)` and tried the following options for saving. The code of both options can be found below:

- Saving using the `keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` function. However, only a .ckpt.data-00000-of-00001 and a .ckpt.index file was returned (so no .meta or .pb file), which I was unable to open
- Saving using the `tf.saved_model.save` function and loading the model with  which resulted in the following error:

```
    WARNING:tensorflow:Looks like there is an object (perhaps variable or layer) that is shared between different layers/models. This may cause issues when restoring the variable values. Object: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent_v2.GRUCell object at 0x7fac1c052eb8>
    WARNING:tensorflow:Inconsistent references when loading the checkpoint into this object graph. Either the Trackable object references in the Python program have changed in an incompatible way, or the checkpoint was generated in an incompatible program.
    
    Two checkpoint references resolved to different objects (<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent_v2.GRUCell object at 0x7fac20648048> and <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent_v2.GRUCell object at 0x7fac1c052eb8>).
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-7-ac3fac428428> in <module>()
          1 model = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Master thesis/NN_data/saved_model/s-20210208-194847'
    ----> 2 new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model)
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, options)
        210       if isinstance(filepath, six.string_types):
        211         loader_impl.parse_saved_model(filepath)
    --> 212         return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
        213 
        214   raise IOError(
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py in load(path, compile, options)
        142   for node_id, loaded_node in keras_loader.loaded_nodes.items():
        143     nodes_to_load[keras_loader.get_path(node_id)] = loaded_node
    --> 144   loaded = tf_load.load_partial(path, nodes_to_load, options=options)
        145 
        146   # Finalize the loaded layers and remove the extra tracked dependencies.
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in load_partial(export_dir, filters, tags, options)
        763     A dictionary mapping node paths from the filter to loaded objects.
        764   """
    --> 765   return load_internal(export_dir, tags, options, filters=filters)
        766 
        767 
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in load_internal(export_dir, tags, options, loader_cls, filters)
        888       try:
        889         loader = loader_cls(object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir,
    --> 890                             ckpt_options, filters)
        891       except errors.NotFoundError as err:
        892         raise FileNotFoundError(
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in __init__(self, object_graph_proto, saved_model_proto, export_dir, ckpt_options, filters)
        159 
        160     self._load_all()
    --> 161     self._restore_checkpoint()
        162 
        163     for node in self._nodes:
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py in _restore_checkpoint(self)
        486     else:
        487       load_status = saver.restore(variables_path, self._checkpoint_options)
    --> 488     load_status.assert_existing_objects_matched()
        489     checkpoint = load_status._checkpoint
        490 
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/util.py in assert_existing_objects_matched(self)
        806           ("Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values, likely "
        807            "due to changes in the Python program: %s") %
    --> 808           (list(unused_python_objects),))
        809     return self
        810 
    
    AssertionError: Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values, likely due to changes in the Python program: [<tf.Variable 'gru_cell_2/bias:0' shape=(2, 648) dtype=float32, numpy=
    array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'gru_cell_2/kernel:0' shape=(108, 648) dtype=float32, numpy=
    array([[ 0.01252341, -0.08176371, -0.00800528, ...,  0.00473534,
            -0.05456369,  0.00294461],
           [-0.02453795,  0.018851  ,  0.07198527, ...,  0.05603079,
            -0.01973856,  0.06883802],
           [-0.06897871, -0.05892187,  0.08031332, ...,  0.07844239,
            -0.06783205, -0.04394536],
           ...,
           [ 0.02367028,  0.07758808, -0.04011653, ..., -0.04074041,
            -0.00352754, -0.03324065],
           [ 0.08708382, -0.0113907 , -0.08592559, ..., -0.07780273,
            -0.07923603,  0.0435034 ],
           [-0.04890796,  0.03626117,  0.01753877, ..., -0.06336015,
            -0.07234246, -0.05076948]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'gru_cell_2/recurrent_kernel:0' shape=(216, 648) dtype=float32, numpy=
    array([[ 0.03453588,  0.01778516, -0.0326081 , ..., -0.02686813,
             0.05017178,  0.01470701],
           [ 0.05364531, -0.02074206, -0.06292176, ..., -0.04883411,
            -0.03006711,  0.03091787],
           [ 0.03928262,  0.01209829,  0.01992464, ..., -0.01726807,
            -0.04125096,  0.00977487],
           ...,
           [ 0.03076804,  0.00477963, -0.03565286, ..., -0.00938745,
            -0.06442262, -0.0124091 ],
           [ 0.03680094, -0.04894238,  0.01765203, ..., -0.11990541,
            -0.01906408,  0.10198548],
           [ 0.00818893, -0.03801145,  0.10376499, ..., -0.01700275,
            -0.02600842, -0.0169891 ]], dtype=float32)>]
```

Shortened code used for (successfully) training and saving the model the model:

```
    model = FeedBack(units=neurons, out_steps=output_len, num_features=108, act_dense=output_activation)
      
    model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr), metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_absolute_percentage_error', keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
    
    cp_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path, save_best_only=True, verbose=0)
    earlyStopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=6, verbose=0,  min_delta=1e-9, mode='auto')
    
    # OPTION 1: USE ModelCheckpoint
    r = model.fit(x=train_x, y=train_y, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, epochs=1,validation_data = (test_x, test_y), callbacks=[earlyStopping, cp_callback], verbose=0)
        
    # OPTION 2: USE tf.saved_model.save()
    !mkdir -p saved_model
    model.save('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Master thesis/NN_data/saved_model/s-%s' % timestring)
    tf.saved_model.save(model, '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Master thesis/NN_data/saved_model/s-%s' % timestring)
```

This was the code used while building the model:

```
    class FeedBack(tf.keras.Model):
        def __init__(self, units, out_steps, num_features, act_dense):
            super().__init__()
            self.out_steps = out_steps
            self.units = units
            self.num_features = num_features
            self.act_dense = act_dense
            self.gru_cell = tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(units)
            # Also wrap the LSTMCell in an RNN to simplify the `warmup` method.
            self.gru_rnn = tf.keras.layers.RNN(self.gru_cell, return_state=True)
            self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_features, activation=act_dense) #self.num_features?
    
        def warmup(self, inputs):
            # inputs.shape => (batch, time, features)
            # x.shape => (batch, lstm_units)
            x, state = self.gru_rnn(inputs)
            
            # predictions.shape => (batch, features)
            prediction = self.dense(x)
            return prediction, state
    
        def call(self, inputs, training=None):
            # Use a TensorArray to capture dynamically unrolled outputs.
            predictions = []
            # Initialize the lstm state
            prediction, state = self.warmup(inputs)
    
            # Insert the first prediction
            predictions.append(prediction)
    
            # Run the rest of the prediction steps
            for _ in range(1, self.out_steps):
                # Use the last prediction as input.
                x = prediction
                # Execute one gru step.
                x, state = self.gru_cell(x, states=state,
                                                                    training=training)
                # Convert the gru output to a prediction.
                prediction = self.dense(x)
                # Add the prediction to the output
                predictions.append(prediction)
    
            # predictions.shape => (time, batch, features)
            predictions = tf.stack(predictions)
            # predictions.shape => (batch, time, features)
            predictions = tf.transpose(predictions, [1, 0, 2])
            return predictions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the problem, think it, is that in `__init__` you wrap the `gru_cell` in a `layers.RNN`. This causes the same `gru_cell` to be used twice: once in `warmup()` and then again in `call()`. For training this is not an issue but, as you noticed, it will fail when saving the model.

Replace your custom RNN layer with a `layers.GRU`

Change this:

```py
def __init__(self, units, out_steps, num_features, act_dense):
    ...
    self.gru_cell = tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(units)
    # Also wrap the LSTMCell in an RNN to simplify the `warmup` method.
    self.gru_rnn = tf.keras.layers.RNN(self.gru_cell, return_state=True)
    ...
```

To this:

```py
def __init__(self, units, out_steps, num_features, act_dense):
    ...
    self.gru_cell = tf.keras.layers.GRUCell(units)
    self.gru_rnn = tf.keras.layers.GRU(units, return_state=True)
    ...
```

*(edit)*
**NOTE:** The `gru_cell` and the `gru_rnn` layers will not be sharing their weights as they do in the original code. In that sense the original version is preferable since there the same `GRUCell` operate on the whole sequence.

In my version the `layers.GRU` operate on the input sequence after which the state will be passed on to the `layers.GRUCell`. This has the drawback that the weights for the `layers.GRUCell` will have to optimised (learnt) separately and do not benefit form using the same weights as the `layers.GRU`, and vice versa.

Comment: Hi Supercluster, thanks for your suggestion, it indeed solved my problem. However, the number of parameters to be trained also doubled, since both the GRU cell and GRU layer are defined individually. Do both the gru_cell and gru_rnn share the same weights, or are they trained independently? Performance-wise, there were no changes, but I'm curious to learn what happens under the hood. Thanks!

Comment: You are right. That is something I did not think of. The GRU cell and the GRU layer do not share their weights. The weights for the GRU cell and GRU layer will be optimised individually, which probably will lead to less good predictions (greater errors) since the GRU cell do not benefit from the weights that the GRU layer "has learned", but instead the GRU cell has to "relearn" its own weights, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is on the filepath that you give to the ModelCheckpoint callback, it should be an hdf5 file.

For example in my case :

```py
ckpt_name = '/work/.../weights/{}.hdf5'.format(log_name)

...
callbacks = [
            TensorBoardImage(...),
            tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=ckpt_name)
        ]
...
model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, validation_freq=1, epochs=FLAGS['epochs'],
                    callbacks=callbacks)
```